# How to reshape a this list vertical to horizontal

Tags: python, numpy

i have a list arranged like this:

```
0         [1, 6]
1         [2, 7]
3         [3, 8]
4         [4, 9]
5         [5, 10]
```

but I am trying to transpose like this:

```
0         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1         [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Please help...

Comment: This post shows no research or effort on your part.

Comment: I have tried transpose which hasnt worked i am lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, to me this looks like a single column dataframe with a list of two elements in each row of the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[[1, 6], [2 ,7], [3, 8], [4, 9],[5, 10]]})
```

Try this:

```
pd.concat([df['col1'].str[i].rename(f'{i}').to_frame().T 
           for i in range(len(df.iloc[0, 0]))]).agg(list, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1    [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
dtype: object
```

Comment: That was the problem it is stored in as a dataframe but in lists of 2 on the 1D, very confusing.  Was hoping for a quick solution to take out the list and just leave it as a dataframe

Answer (score 2):

In numpy, for transposing you can do:

```
array.T
```